# $A(n) = f(m)$ numbers of $f(m)$ followed by $f(m)$ numbers of $0$. $f(m)$ is the remainder when $m$ is divided by $9$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> A series is formed in the following manner:
>   $A(1) = 1; $
>   $A(n) = f(m)$ numbers of $f(m)$ followed by $f(m)$ numbers of $0$;
>   $m$ is the number of digits in $A(n-1).$
>   Find $A(30)$.
>   Here $f(m)$ is the remainder when $m$ is divided by $9$.

I have no idea about this problem. Any hint will be helpful.
**Note**: This is a Problem from BDMO $2010$ National.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me how A(n) is defined. Could you please provide A(2), A(3) for an example?

Comment: @Jsevillamol Same Problem to me. But the question is same as posted.

Comment: Concretely, I do not understand what does the expression X numbers of Y mean.

Comment: @Jsevillamol X numbers of Y means YYYY.....YY. i.e. X times Y is written.

Comment: I think A(1) = 10 and A(2) = 2200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, lets bring this down with some Modular-Arithmetic-fu. We can see that the value of A(n) is uniquely determined by the number of digits of A(n-1) mod 9. We will use D(n) to mean 'the number of digits of A(n) mod 9'.

Clearly, $D(n) = D(n-1)*2 (mod\ 9)$.

We can transform this recursive formula into a direct one: 
$D(n)= D(1)*2^{n-1} (mod\ 9)=2^{n-1} (mod\ 9)$

Now we substitute $D(29)= 2^{28}(mod\ 9) = 2^{3*9+1}(mod\ 9) =(2³)^9\cdot2^1(mod\ 9)=(-1)^9\cdot 2\ (mod\ 9) = -2\ (mod\ 9)=7 $.

The value of $A(30)$ is determined by this, and it is $A(30) = 777777770000000$

Comment: notice $2^3 = 8 = -1 mod_9$ so $$2^{27} = {2^3}^9 = -1^9 = -1$$ (all in $mod_9$)